# How to add permanent labels to each feature in a geoJSON layer?

Tags: leaflet

I have some geoJSON objects brought in from a database and want to display them on a map using Leaflet.

As I have multiple objects visible with the same style icon/marker I don't know which is which until I click on each one at the moment.
I have working code to pop up a box with full information when I click on each object.

What I really want is to have each item with a label visible all the time so I know which one to click on to get more information.

I can see from the .bindTooltip method how to get a fixed label, but when I run my code, only the first object from the geoJSON file gets the label.

I can't find any examples of anyone doing anything similar - any maps with multiple labels are created from manually created points.

The code segment in particular looks like this:

```html
// This shows correct geoJSON name but shows fixed label only for 1 (first) geoJSON object!
function fixedLabel(layer) {
    return layer.feature.properties.name
};
 
function clickLabel (feature,layer) {
    layer.bindPopup("ID: " + feature.properties.id + "<br>Name: " + feature.properties.name + "<br>DateTime: " + feature.properties.vdatetime + "<br>Speed: " + feature.properties.speedknots + " knots<br>CMG: " + feature.properties.cmg + "°");
};
 
var vesselsLayer = L.geoJson(vessels,{
    onEachFeature: clickLabel
    })
    .addTo(map).bindTooltip(fixedLabel, {permanent: true, direction: 'right'}).openTooltip();
    map.fitBounds(vesselsLayer.getBounds());
```

The full code & geoJSON code are in github here:
https://github.com/DPB61/leafletjs_test01

Am I going completely the wrong way about getting labels on each object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding the tooltip to the GeoJSON layer, not to each individual layer contained within it. Try something like this:

```
L.geoJson(vessels,{
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup("ID: " + feature.properties.id + "<br>Name: " + feature.properties.name + "<br>DateTime: " + feature.properties.vdatetime + "<br>Speed: " + feature.properties.speedknots + " knots<br>CMG: " + feature.properties.cmg + "°");
        layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.name, {permanent: true, direction: 'right'}).openTooltip();
    }
}).addTo(map)
```